# MWPhotoBrowser errors on installation

Tags: ios, mwphotobrowser

I've installed [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) using cocoapods but I'm getting the following errors:

```
/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:182:14: Property 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' not found on object of type 'MWPhotoBrowser *'

/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:392:17: No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'prefersStatusBarHidden'

/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:479:16: Property 'barTintColor' not found on object of type 'UINavigationBar *'; did you mean 'tintColor'?

/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:492:79: Property 'barTintColor' not found on object of type 'UINavigationBar *'; did you mean 'tintColor'?

/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:509:20: Property 'barTintColor' not found on object of type 'UINavigationBar *'; did you mean 'tintColor'?

/Users/noor/Documents/Apps/Info.mu.final/Pods/MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser/Classes/MWPhotoBrowser.m:1057:22: No visible @interface for 'MWPhotoBrowser' declares the selector 'setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate'
```

My Podfile contains:

```
platform :ios, '6.1'
pod 'MapBox'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
```

Comment: Please paste your podfile for deep analysis :]

Answer (score 0):

automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, prefersStatusBarHidden and barTintColor are only available in iOS7.

So remove '6.1' and run "pod install" again.

Just have a try, and tell me if it works please!